# Download images from google drive in IPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I'm making an IPhone app where i integrated google drive. Now I want to download images from the drive into app. There are multiple images.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Drive SDK documentation includes complete code snippets in multiple languages showing how to download files:

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads

You should also check the reference guide for `files.get`, which includes Objective-C code:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get